# Render HTML Page with Json data

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have this issue:
I have a get request that I serve using router.get (Express). 
In this function I use to take datas from my sql db. Now i have this data in JSON format.
 I want to pass the json datas to handlebars and to send the response to the client with the datas rendered inside the html only (Render is completely made on server side).
Maybe I' m getting a little bit confusing: 
Is there a solution for what I want to do?

Express:

```
//CHAT
router.get('/chatlist', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
    let mittente = req.user.id;
    findUsersChat(mittente)
    .then(Chats=>{
        getChatData(Chats,mittente).then(ChatList=>{
            console.log("Lista2: " +ChatList);
            var obj=JSON.parse(ChatList);
            res.render('chatlist') ;
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))

    });

})
```

Handlebars

```
<section id="gigs" class="container">
    <h1>Chats Available</h1>

        {{#each obj}}
        <h1>{{Nome}}</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <form method="POST" action="/users/chat">  
            <p>Utente numero : {{@index}}</p>
            <label for="name" value={{Nome}}>{{Nome}}</label>

          </form>

        </div>
        {{/each}}
  </section>
```

Comment: It looks like you are not passing the obj data to your view. Can you try: res.render('chatlist', {obj: Chats})

Comment: It works. Can I ask you what  {obj:Chats} do? The result is that only index is showed. Why? Can I ask you how can i solve it and how to show also {{nome}}?@Mihai

Comment: can you post the output of this command: console.log("Lista2: " +ChatList); Based on that I can write the full answer

Comment: @Mihai   Lista2: [{"id":7,"Nome":"ciccio","Cognome":"sasiccio","DataNascita":null,"Professione":null,"Email":"sasicc@gmail.com","Password":"$2a$10$Wi5SELvNIMDcchE3O2FcvOUcpt4EJOdbC8lowzL/7w8dEnGtTP6ZK"},{"id":8,"Nome":"Dio","Cognome":"Porco","DataNascita":null,"Professione":null,"Email":"porc0di0@gmail.com","Password":"$2a$10$BfKc8sSLrU7JZFw/JZ1iHe5Sg.xSlfWmpOIih9RCrV35c0xHyjWna"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not passing the array (ChatList) to your view.
You can do that by changing your code to this:

```js
...
        getChatData(Chats,mittente).then(ChatList=>{
            console.log("Lista2: " +ChatList);
            res.render('chatlist', {objects: ChatList}) ;
        })
...
```

By doing this an array "objects" will be available in your view and you can iterator over it.

Your page now should become:

```html
<section id="gigs" class="container">
    <h1>Chats Available</h1>

        {{#each objects}}
        <h1>{{./Nome}}</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <form method="POST" action="/users/chat">  
            <p>Utente numero : {{@index}}</p>
            <label for="name" value={{./Nome}}>{{./Nome}}</label>

          </form>

        </div>
        {{/each}}
  </section>
```

Comment: man of the weekend! I had only to change {objects:obj} , but you really helped me! Thank you :)

Comment: figurati. in bocca al lupo!